# meaning of Grid resolution

Tags: meteorology, geophysics, geology, earth-observation

I have some queries regarding grid. What does this mean.
The grid has spatial resolution of 1/2 degrees latitude × 2/3 degrees longitude.?

Comment: see http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/7172/what-exactly-is-a-model-grid

Comment: thanks alot for replying. i have already seen the link.I want to confirm one thing. The normal world grid has -90 to 90(180 points) lat & -180 to 180(360 points) longitude points. If a grid shows these point with 361 points for latitude & 540 points for longitude. Does this means the grid has resolution of 1/2x 2/3 ?

Comment: There isn't really any such thing as a "normal world grid". But if the whole world is covered as you describe, and the grid is a lat/lon one, then yes, it's 1/2 * 2/3 degrees. (@fred - you're using 360 degrees for latitude, which is odd :-))